# How to make clone element stay after Submit button clicked?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, clone

I have a row that will added automatically when I click 'Add Row' button. The row created by using clone() method. When I click 'Submit' button. The new row gone and didnt stay in that page. How to make it stay with the input in the textbox after the page is load?

Below is my code for that row:

```
<div id="rows">
  <div class="p2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" runat="server"/>
    <input id="txt1" type="text" runat="server" maxlength="16" value="0.00" /> &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="p3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="p4">
    <input id="txt2" type="text" runat="server" maxlength="16" value="0.00"/> &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="p5">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="p6">
    <input id="txt3" type="text" runat="server" maxlength="16" value="0.00"/> &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <span style="color:red;">*</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my javascript code:

```
var cloneCount = 1;
//Add new row
$("#addrow").click(function () {
  $('#rows')
    .clone(true).find('input:text').val("").end()
    .attr('id', 'rows' + cloneCount++, 'class', 'block')
    .insertAfter('[id^=rows]:last');
  return false;
});
```

below is my code for the button:

```
<div id="bttns" style="text-align:center;">
  <button id="addrow" >Add Row</button>
  <button onclick="validate()" >Submit</button>
</div>
```

I'm using VS2012 and this project were ASPX web form. Do I need to do some code-behind? What are the problem inside my code? Really needs your help and I'm new to C# and asp.net.

Comment: Yes.. you need to update your `dataset` from backend for the element where you are binding it. How you are binding the dataset to your `grid`?

Comment: the dynamically added elements are temporary, meaning if you reaload the page it is gone.. You need to save them somewhere.. either in your database and build it back on realod, Or save in browser session or local storage (which both are not a good idea)

Comment: i see. thats why the row was gone after the page loaded. Actually this project were done to be exactly as the original, the functionality, but in different way of method. So, just for testing, is it ok for me to save in browser session like session state in this problem? @rajshekar

Comment: im not binding it to any dataset as this is only page without link to any database. if i need to edit in the code behind, could you give me some example, as a reference for me, to solve this problem? @guruprasad

Comment: I might need to see how you are feeding these data to client side without database included!

Comment: @Syafah are you using MVC or webforms?

Comment: @rajshekar im using webforms.